# Hive argument using Variable Substitution (-d|--define) fails with a string argument

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive

When I run the a hive script with the command

> hive -d arg_partition1="p1" -f test.hql

It returns the error

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 3:36 Invalid table alias or column reference 'p1': (possible column names are: line, partition1)

Script with name test.hql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (Line STRING)
    PARTITIONED BY (partition1 STRING);
ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (partition1="p1") LOCATION '/user/test/hive_test_data';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE partition1=${arg_partition1};
```

If I modify the partition to be an integer then it works fine and returns the correct results.

How do I run a Hive script with a string argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to escape your quotes when invoking hive, such as `-d arg_partition1=\"p1\"` for this to work.

However, I don't see why you'd have to add the quotes to the replacement string in any case. Presumably you know the data types of your fields when writing the query, so if `partition1` is a string then include the quotes in the query, such as `WHERE partition1="${arg_partition1}";` and if it's an integer just leave them out entirely.